# CORS policy doesn't work for specific port. How to fix it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have to nginx sites on my server, one on port 80 and one on 8087. Cors policy from spring works for http://51.91.251.253 but does not for http://51.91.251.253:8087. How I can fix it to let both of them access server?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
    registry.addMapping("/**")
//                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            .allowedOrigins("http://51.91.251.253")
            .allowedOrigins("http://51.91.251.253:8087");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `corsConfig.allowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://51.91.251.253","http://51.91.251.253:8087"));`